# dplyr sample_n where n is the value of a grouped variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following grouped data frame, and I would like to use the function `dplyr::sample_n` to extract rows from this data frame for each group. I want to use the value of the grouped variable `NDG` in each group as the number of rows to extract from each group.

```
> dg.tmp <- structure(list(Gene = c("CAMK1", "GHRL", "TIMP4", "CAMK1", "GHRL", 
"TIMP4", "ARL8B", "ARPC4", "SEC13", "ARL8B", "ARPC4", "SEC13"
), GLB = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10), NDG = c(1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), .Names = c("Gene", "GLB", 
"NDG"))

> dg <- dg.tmp %>% 
     dplyr::group_by(GLB,NDG)

> dg
Source: local data frame [12 x 3]
Groups: GLB, NDG

      Gene GLB NDG
1    A4GNT   3   1
2    ABTB1   3   1
3     AHSG   3   1
4    A4GNT   3   2
5    ABTB1   3   2
6     AHSG   3   2
7    AADAC  10   1
8  ABHD14B  10   1
9   ACVR2B  10   1
10   AADAC  10   2
11 ABHD14B  10   2
12  ACVR2B  10   2
```

For example, assuming the correct random selection, I want the code

```
> dg %>% dplyr::sample_n(NDG)
```

to output:

```
Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
Groups: GLB, NDG

      Gene GLB NDG
1    A4GNT   3   1
2    A4GNT   3   2
3    ABTB1   3   2
4    AADAC  10   1
5    AADAC  10   2
6  ABHD14B  10   2
```

However, it gives the following error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'NDG' not found
```

By way of comparison, `dplyr::slice` gives the correct output when I use the code

```
> dg %>% dplyr::slice(1:unique(NDG))
```

It *is* slightly hackish using `unique` in this context, however, the code

```
> dg %>% dplyr::slice(1:NDG)
```

returns the following warning messages

```
Warning messages:
1: In slice_impl(.data, dots) :
  numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used
2: In slice_impl(.data, dots) :
  numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used
3: In slice_impl(.data, dots) :
  numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used
4: In slice_impl(.data, dots) :
  numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used
```

clearly because `NDG` is being evaluated (in the appropriate environment) as `c(1,1,1)` or `c(2,2,2)`, and hence `1:NDG` returns the above warning.

---

Regarding why I obtain the error, I know that the code Hadley uses for the method sample_n.grouped_df is

```
sample_n.grouped_df <- function(tbl, size, replace = FALSE, weight = NULL,
  .env = parent.frame()) {

  assert_that(is.numeric(size), length(size) == 1, size >= 0)
  weight <- substitute(weight)

  index <- attr(tbl, "indices")
  sampled <- lapply(index, sample_group, frac = FALSE,
    tbl = tbl, size = size, replace = replace, weight = weight, .env = .env)
  idx <- unlist(sampled) + 1

  grouped_df(tbl[idx, , drop = FALSE], vars = groups(tbl))
}
```

which can be found on the relevant [Github page](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/R/grouped-df.r). Thus I obtain the error because `sample_n.grouped_df` cannot find the variable `NGD` because it's not looking in the correct environment.

Consequently, is there a neat way of using `sample_n` on `dg` to obtain

```
Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
Groups: GLB, NDG

      Gene GLB NDG
1    A4GNT   3   1
2    A4GNT   3   2
3    ABTB1   3   2
4    AADAC  10   1
5    AADAC  10   2
6  ABHD14B  10   2
```

by using random sampling on each group?

Comment: your example df `dg` returns an error

Comment: Thanks for that, edited it. It turns out that using `dput` on a grouped dataframe and entering the code back into the terminal gives an error, because it can't find the name of the grouping variable. For example, copying and pasting the output of `dput(dg)` into the console gives the error `object 'GLB' not found`. Strange...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible answer, but I'm not convinced it's the optimal answer: permute the rows of the data frame with `dplyr::sample_frac` (and a fraction of 1), then slice the required number of rows:

```
> set.seed(1)
> dg %>% 
      dplyr::sample_frac(1) %>%
      dplyr::slice(1:unique(NDG))
```

This gives the correct output.

```
Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
Groups: GLB, NDG

    Gene GLB NDG
1  A4GNT   3   1
2   AHSG   3   2
3  A4GNT   3   2
4 ACVR2B  10   1
5  AADAC  10   2
6 ACVR2B  10   2
```

And I suppose I can just write a function to do this in one line if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative answer, although the one above seems fine:

```
dg %>% 
  sample_frac(1) %>%
  filter(row_number() <= NDG) %>%
  arrange(NDG)

Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
Groups: GLB, NDG

     Gene GLB NDG
1    AHSG   3   1
2   ABTB1   3   2
3    AHSG   3   2
4 ABHD14B  10   1
5   AADAC  10   2
6 ABHD14B  10   2
```

The `sample_frac` reorders the dataframe, and assigns new row numbers to each group, and then you just take the first NDG number of rows. The `arrange` doesn't do anything but reorder your data to make it look like in your desired output.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem using grouped dfs, and remembered there's a very elegant way to do this in `purrr`, as outlined in [this very helpful tutorial](https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/ls12_different-sized-samples.html):

```
library(purrr)

dg.tmp %>% 
  nest(-GLB, -NDG) %>% 
  mutate(data = map2(data, NDG, sample_n)) %>% 
  unnest
```

One advantage is that it doesn't require the permutation of ALL rows of data as with `sample_frac`, which could be quite costly with a large dataframe.

Comment: Amazing solution!