# Sample n random rows per group in a dataframe with dplyr when some observations have less than n rows

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

I have a data frame with two categorical variables.

```
samples<-c("A","A","A","A","B","B")
groups<-c(1,1,1,2,1,1)
df<- data.frame(samples,groups)
df
  samples groups
1       A      1
2       A      1
3       A      1
4       A      2
5       B      1
6       B      1
```

The result that I would like to have is for each given observation (sample-group) to downsample (randomly, this is important) the data frame to a maximum of X rows and keep all obervation for which appear less than X times. In the example here X=2. Is there an easy way to do this? The issue that I have is that observation 4 (A,2) appears only once, thus dplyr sample_n would not work.

desired output

```
  samples groups
1       A      1
2       A      1
3       A      2
4       B      1
5       B      1
```

Comment: I assume that the data.frame consists of more than 2 columns and that not all of them are used for grouping

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R (and dplyr?) - Sampling from a dataframe by group, up to a maximum sample size of n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52816423/r-and-dplyr-sampling-from-a-dataframe-by-group-up-to-a-maximum-sample-size)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sample minimum of number of rows or `x` for each group :

```
library(dplyr)

x <- 2
df %>% group_by(samples, groups) %>% sample_n(min(n(), x))

#  samples groups
#  <chr>    <dbl>
#1 A            1
#2 A            1
#3 A            2
#4 B            1
#5 B            1
```

However, note that `sample_n()` has been super-seeded in favor of `slice_sample` but `n()` doesn't work with `slice_sample`. There is an open issue [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/5478) for it.

---

However, as @tmfmnk mentioned we don't need to call `n()` here. Try :

```
df %>% group_by(samples, groups) %>% slice_sample(n = x)
```

Comment: Not sure whether it produces a consistent solution across all scenarios, but according the documentation of `slice_sample()` `If n is greater than the number of rows in the group (or prop > 1), the result will be silently truncated to the group size. If the proportion of a group size is not an integer, it is rounded down.`. So here, using `slice_sample(n = 2)` produces the same results as your code.

Comment: @tmfmnk Thanks, I somehow missed that in the documentation. I have updated the answer based on your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you guys, `slice_sample` is perfectly working.

Comment: None of this is working for me with dplyr 1.0.9. While the documentation still reads the same as @tmfmnk comment, if nrow is less than the sample number I get an error that it cannot take a sample larger than the population when replace=FALSE. When trying the min() approach, I get an error that n has to be a constant.

Answer (score 1):

One option with `data.table`:

```
df[df[, .I[sample(.N, min(.N, X))], by = .(samples, groups)]$V1]

   samples groups
1:       A      1
2:       A      1
3:       A      2
4:       B      1
5:       B      1
```