# How to use sample_n within a for loop and create dataframe

Tags: r, sample

I am getting this error

> 'Error: Argument 1 must have names'

can somebody help?

```
temp <- data.frame()
for (i in 2:3){
temp <- rbind(temp,without_first %>% filter(sz==i) %>% samp(i,replace=TRUE))
}
```

Data structure

```
id     timepoint  size
1001   time30      2
1001   time60      2
1001   time90      2
1002   time60      1
1002  time90       1
```

I am trying to randomly select 2 observations for id=1001,1 observations for id=1002 etc.I have many such subjects in dataset.
My code which is given above is not working. Can someone suggest code in R ?

I have also tried

```
data<-%>% group_by(id)%>%sample_n(size,replace=TRUE)
```

does not work.Please suggest some code in R ?

Comment: Aslo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950016/dplyr-sample-n-where-n-is-the-value-of-a-grouped-variable

Comment: Please also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4550695

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `for` loop. You could directly specify  `size` in `sample_n` using the `first` value from `size` column for each `id`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  sample_n(first(size))


#    id timepoint  size
#  <int> <fct>     <int>
#1  1001 time60        2
#2  1001 time30        2
#3  1002 time90        1
```

Comment: @user11358720 You can consider to accept the answer by clicking on check mark next to vote button so that it can be marked as solved.